# Displaying all icons in a glyph

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a widget UI where the user can manipulate widgets and text. One of the UI functions needed is to select an icon from the list of icons in a glyph and as I'm using twitter bootstrap it should be possible to select the "icon-" classes in the CSS in JavaScript then display them in a DIV. However I'm still relatively new to web development so unsure how I can loop through all the CSS classes selecting all the "icon-" classes. I can see how to do that with a selector to search the HTML body, for example with `$.find("[class^='icon-']");` but I'm not sure how to do similar to search the CSS file itself and extract a list of CSS icon classes.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: `$.find("[class^='icon-']");` means: all elements with the attribute `class`with a value starting with `icon-`...

Comment: Yes but this won't search the CSS file AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work if your browser implements the [CSSStyleSheet interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet):

```
var icons = [];
var cssRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules; // your bootstrap.css
for (var i=0; i<cssRules.length; i++) {
  var selectorText = cssRules[i].selectorText;
  if (selectorText && selectorText.match(/^\.icon-[a-z_-]+$/)) {
    icons.push(selectorText);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V2wjX/

Comment: It's quite random (only works after clicking "Run" after page load). Really depends on what stylesheet gets loaded first. (wouldn't recommend)

Comment: Absolutely, relying on a hard-coded index is never a good idea. The script is just an example :-)

Comment: maybe if you can iterate over stylesheets and get the path, there's something to do :)

Comment: According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t10) this is quite widely supported (ofc. not in IE), so this may be a good approach as well. The hard thing is finding out which is the CSS file that we want the selectors of.

Comment: At least IE9 implements the `cssRules` property.

Comment: Yep, works a treat. I use IE10 and this looks like an efficient solution. Thank you. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I can think of is creating an array of the possible values, then looping through them. Here, I made it for you: ([from this page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons))

```
var icons = ["glass","music","search","envelope","heart","star","star-empty","user","film","th-large","th","th-list","ok","remove","zoom-in","zoom-out","off","signal","cog","trash","home","file","time","road","download-alt","download","upload","inbox","play-circle","repeat","refresh","list-alt","lock","flag","headphones","volume-off","volume-down","volume-up","qrcode","barcode","tag","tags","book","bookmark","print","camera","font","bold","italic","text-height","text-width","align-left","align-center","align-right","align-justify","list","indent-left","indent-right","facetime-video","picture","pencil","map-marker","adjust","tint","edit","share","check","move","step-backward","fast-backward","backward","play","pause","stop","forward","fast-forward","step-forward","eject","chevron-left","chevron-right","plus-sign","minus-sign","remove-sign","ok-sign","question-sign","info-sign","screenshot","remove-circle","ok-circle","ban-circle","arrow-left","arrow-right","arrow-up","arrow-down","share-alt","resize-full","resize-small","plus","minus","asterisk","exclamation-sign","gift","leaf","fire","eye-open","eye-close","warning-sign","plane","calendar","random","comment","magnet","chevron-up","chevron-down","retweet","shopping-cart","folder-close","folder-open","resize-vertical","resize-horizontal","hdd","bullhorn","bell","certificate","thumbs-up","thumbs-down","hand-right","hand-left","hand-up","hand-down","circle-arrow-right","circle-arrow-left","circle-arrow-up","circle-arrow-down","globe","wrench","tasks","filter","briefcase","fullscreen"]
```

Now you can loop through this array, and create the elements as needed.

```
for (var i=0,l=icons.length; i<l; i++){
    var el = document.createElement('i');
    el.className = 'icon-'+icons[i];
    document.getElementById("iconContainer").appendChild(el);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/QwJD8/)

---

As for searching the CSS, I can suggest you to write a function  like this:

You somehow get the contents of a CSS file into a string, using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) ([jqXHR](http://sharpkit.net/help/sharpkit.jquery/SharpKit.jQuery/jqXHR/)) possibly.

Then, write a **very** basic parsing script, which accepts the CSS string as the parameter.

```
function getIcons(cssStr){
    var matches = cssStr.match(/\.icon\-\w*.*\{/g), icons = [];
    for (var i=0,l=matches.length; i<l; i++) icons.push(matches[i].replace(/\.icon\-/g,'').replace(/\W/g,''));
    return icons;
}
```

This will give you the array shown before.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/Yyzxy/)

Comment: OK, I can see how this can work in JS, but I want to use different font files without having to hard code the names if possible. Is there a way to search a CSS file for all "icon-" classes (eg. selector)?

Comment: Hi DJDavid, thanks. Is there a JavaScript way of getting the CSS in a string? Your suggested method should work although the JSFiddle isn't working for me in IE10 (your code looks good though)

Comment: @deandob [It is possible, yes.](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/) As for the code not working, I have no idea why. I'm on Windows XP and cannot test above IE8, in fact I didn't really test the code in IE, because I assumed it was working. It may be related to a JSFiddle issue rather than an issue in my code, try running the script externally.

Comment: No problems, I'll play with it some more, I understand the principle.